# Firebase and Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, firebase

I am struggling a little bit while trying to implement firebase in unity, firebase do not yet provide a unity sdk and I was considering these options:

1) create native plugins for iOS and Android that wraps the firebase sdk and methods that I need

2) use IKVM to create a dll from the firebase .jar, I know someone has done it but I have not read yet about a 100% working method

3) build everything from scratch on top of the firebase REST api

what do you advice? have you got some experience with the topic, someone out there has made firebase work with unity?? :D

thanks

Comment: Hi user1279694, Firebase employee here. I'd definitely pick either option 1 or 3. For option 3, be sure to use the REST streaming API, which offers the same real-time benefits as the native (JavaScript, iOS and Android) APIs.

Comment: Hi Frank, thanks for the answer! :) is there a firebase unity sdk in pipeline? thank you

Comment: There is no Unity SDK in the pipeline at present. There have been a few requests in the past and yours will be added to the feature discussion.

Comment: say @FrankvanPuffelen surprised you didn't add the Unity news on here big guy!

Comment: also @FrankvanPuffelen I direct your attention: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35777072/intagrating-firebase-into-unity-project

Answer (score 10):

Firebase has officially Unity supported now.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/setup

Import FirebaseAnalytics.unitypackage(Download From Firebase Website Or direct link https://dl.google.com/firebase/sdk/unity/firebase_unity_sdk_1.0.0.zip)

Answer (score 6):

You can look [this beta](https://github.com/firebase/Firebase-Unity) tool, with this u can build for Android and IOS from Unity.

Comment: Thanks for answering Mario, I was just looking for old questions to update. :-)  For those interested, the Firebase Unity plugin linked uses the first approach mentioned by OP: it wraps the native Android and iOS libraries from Firebase.

Comment: Wow that is great! Thank you for linking it! Is there any experience with the stability and performance of this "beta tool" approach?  - I use Firebase (Auth/Database/Storage) within two Android apps and I would love to use it also from inside Unity...

Answer (score 1):

Each Plugin have firebase fun.

https://github.com/unity-plugins/Firebase-Admob-Unity
Google Firebase Unity Admob Plugin

Google Firebase Unity Admob Plugin provides a way to integrate firebase admob ads in Unity3D Game and u3d app. You can use it for Unity iOS and Android App with the same c# or js code.It support all native firebase admob features such as Native Express Ad

Google Firebase Unity Admob Plugin Features

Platforms supported in one plugin :

Android, Based Admob SDK v9.0 (part of Google Firebase service)
 iOS, via SDK v7.8.0
 Support all native events
 AdRequest targeting methods,such as children target,test mode
 Not need change Android package name
 Very simple API
 Based on FireBase SDK Version
Ad Types:

Banner(All Banner Type and Custom banner sizes)
 Interstitial (text, picture, video)
 Rewarded Video
 Native Express Ad

https://github.com/unity-plugins/google-service-unity

Google Service Unity Plugin

Google Service Unity Plugin is a Unity Plugin For Google Service.Include Google Admob Unity,Firebase Analytic Unity,Google Game API Unity. Login,Achievement,Leaderboard,Event,Quest,Snapshot,RealTimePlayGame,TurnbasedPlayGame API are supported and easy to use with c# or js.

Answer (score 0):

Currently it's very easy to add Firebase to your Unity project as long as you follow specific [prerequisites](https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/setup#prerequisites). If you're building for Android or iOS then you're good to go, but the same doesn't happen if you're [building for WebGL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60883058/5675325).

According to [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/setup), it can be done following the next steps

1. [Create a Firebase project](https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/setup#create-firebase-project)
2. [Register your app with Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/setup#register-app)
3. [Add Firebase configuration files](https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/setup#add-config-file)
4. [Add Firebase Unity SDKs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/setup#add-sdks)