# Integrating Firebase into unity project

Tags: unity-game-engine, firebase

Does anyone know how to connect Firebase to Unity3d 5?

Or can anyone suggest me a better way to receive a username and password and transfer it to an external server and also control variables in the code through the server?

Comment: @JoeBlow Any progress?

Comment: as-salam @MohammadFaizanKhan - not sure what you mean?  Another great option is you use **back4app** which is simply Parse but with a new name and owner now.  there is a huge amount of QA/examples on using Parse, so it literally couldn't be easier

Comment: Also do note that **UNITY IS OPENING THEIR OWN BAAS SOON**.  that will be the only realistic option once they start it.  it's already in beta testing.

Comment: regarding Firebase in Unity, google "using Firebase in Unity", example http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/tutorial-shift-painlessly-to-firebase-from-parse.410743/  **"Tutorial -  Shift Painlessly to Firebase from Parse"**

Comment: thanks @JoeBlow ! nothing work for me.:( trying from 2 days http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39073976/sending-data-from-unity-to-firebase-producing-error-invalid-data-couldnt-par

Answer (score 0):

Firebase has officially Unity supported now.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/setup