# FIREBASE + UNITY

Tags: unity-game-engine, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need to create a database for a game in the Unity3D, is a base where I can insert information and images and thus, in the application downloaded by users this content appears. I would Firebase use, today there is some method to do this?

Comment: See https://github.com/firebase/Firebase-Unity

Comment: See https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/setup and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29184090/firebase-and-unity/40552415#40552415